# Open/Create blog post page on OctoberCMS

Tags: laravel, octobercms, octobercms-backend

I used this link:
[Hide content of blog posts when displaying blog post list in OctoberCMS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31804045/hide-content-of-blog-posts-when-displaying-blog-post-list-in-octobercms/32135574#32135574)

as a tutorial to create a new plugin and show my blog posts by my own style (just post title, date, etc)

But now I need to show the full content of the post. I've migrated from wordpress, where each post creates a new page automaticaly. Does OctoberCMS do the same thing? If yes, how can I relate the post title to the post page. (if not I'll create a "read more" link and show the content on the same page, but, if the users get redirect to the post page, it would be great!)

thanks!
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`October CMS` is not like `word-press`, To make `posts` you need actual `plugin` and with in that plugin you can `add models/tables for you post data`

Then you need to **create components** which can `show` your records to `front-end`.

> If you are not using **rainlab-blog** plugin then you need to do this stuff

So basically you need to create this things :

`Page` where you want to `list all post` and then add `listposts` component which will show `list of posts` (**you need to make it manually**) then for that `component` you need to pass `single post detail page`

**For single post** again you create `new page` add `another component` which can read `slug` and `show respective post data`

For `redirection from post list` to `single post` you need to `create link` as you are passing `single post detail page` to `component` you can create **link with slug** and redirect to `single post page`

For better reference check out https://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-blog plugin and `read` its **documentation and code**

Then you understand how things works.

> Its kind of pain to do thing manually as you are coming from wordpress, But it will give you more control and more flexiblity

Once you made your plugin you can **fully Extend it and reuse it** as you want.

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: Hardik, thanks for your response! I'll read all that documentation.

Comment: yes, if find any difficulties you can ask :) , october CMS more like MVC, where `components` are `VC` (view controller) at front side and plugin models are `M` (model)

Comment: I've migrated from wordpress to october exactly because of the "freedom of control and more flexibility" that octoberCMS offers. But just with your answer I got the idea on how to do it.

thanks again!
Best Regards

Comment: welcome mate,  you will get freedom you seek :) for sure

Comment: I'm usually very lazy to watch tutorial videos (I do prefer to read tutorials, hehehe)... but... that tutorial video on RainLab's Blog Plugin, maaaaan, it's very enlightening. Thanks!

I'll post here the results when I finish it.

Comment: Hardik, hello again! hehehe... I'm just having a hard time now on how to hide the posts that are not flagged as "published". I have two post created but both are not published (those posts are just for test, and I'll keep one of them as a model, so my wife can use it to post new content, as she doesn't know anything bout html)

thanks again!

Comment: you are using `rainlab-post` plugin or custom bulid one ?

Comment: I'm using a custom one. I'm trying to edit my default.htm. It is like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/mrodrigoja/n93ettmr/

Comment: tryed to add 
{% if post.isPublished() %} right below {% for post in posts %} but it didn't work

Comment: `{% if post.isPublished() %} ...code...  {% endif %}` this should work, and your `post model` should have method `isPublished` and it should return `true` or `false`

Comment: Well... so...
I've deleted the posts and created another one called "tutorial". This one I didn't checked the "published" flag... and now it stays hidden...
I don't know what happened.... But it's working now. So... thats good!

Hardik, thanks again for all your help. May you have a "Happy Carnaval", hehe. Regards!